# How to run the Flutter pinball code on my PC? The code is stuck on dependencies and many error

Tags: flutter, dart, intl, flutter-localizations

T'm trying to merge and run the code to my own PC from repo github https://github.com/flutter/pinball
but all the code is error, and it says:
Because pinball depends on flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.0, intl 0.18.0 is required.
So, because pinball depends on intl ^0.17.0, version solving failed.

The code is also complex too. It's hard to fix and solve the dependencies and some code error.

I hope the code can be run on my PC, thats all.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use Flutter version 2.10.5, but otherwise try to upgrade the intl in the pubspec.